# Show html form inside video

Tags: javascript, html5-video, overlay

Videos shown in some course videos like those in Coursera has questions embedded inside a lecture video where a student can answer it at get feedback. Looking for suggestions on for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the css property z-index and put the video below the form.